# How to manage bootstrap breakpoints in a website using class col-*

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm currently thinking about how to manage my breakpoints. For the moment, i only use the class col-lg-* on my div cause i'm working on desktop and don't need to worry about breakpoint problems for the moment.

But in the future, we'll have to deal with that. So, i was wondering how to do it :

Adding the class col-xs, col-sd, col-md on my div seems a bit tiring ... I guess there are other way of doing it using media queries maybe ?

thanks.

Comment: You do not think aobut media queries. You can do it by `col-sm-*,col-md-*, col-lg-*, col-xs-*`

Comment: That's how you do it. Bootstrap has done the media queries for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BootStrap **col-xs-**** is for Extra small **devices Phones (<768px)** , **col-sm-**** is for **Small devices
Tablets (≥768px)** and **col-md-** is for **Medium devices Desktops** and for **Large devices Desktops** (≥1200px) use **col-lg-**..

so include all four classes, it reduces your effort..

Refer bootstrap website for more...

Comment: so what you mean is that i should from the start, include all for classes wherever i use one of them ? As i only use col-lg* for the moment, i'll have to go back on all my projet in order to add the 4 over classes ?  I thought about that before but that makes the code less clear (to read), so i thought that maybe there was another way which will avoid me to overload my html code.

Comment: Or else use Media quires and hard code the width for col-lg-* according to the screen size....

Comment: You don't need to include all 4 classes all the time, since the smaller grid classes also apply to larger screens unless you override them with classes specifically for the larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

If use any one of class and then also Bootstrap library will manage to show content in decent way on most of device size.

**Extra small devices (phones, up to 480px): No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap**

**Small devices (tablets, 768px and up): @media (min-width: @screen-sm) { ... }**

**Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up): @media (min-width: @screen-md) { ... }**

**Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up): @media (min-width: @screen-lg) { ... }**